# ¿Como puedo sacar datos de una lista y meterlos a un arreglo en Js?

Tags: javascript

```js
//FUCNION ABRIR POPUP=================================================================================
  function clickAbrirPopupPedidoCarrito(idEquipo){
    idEquipoGlobal = idEquipo;
      clickIngresarCarritoEquipo();
    $("#popupAgregarCarrito").modal("toggle");
  }
  //====================================================================================================

  //FUCNION INGRESAR EQUIPO=============================================================================
  function clickIngresarCarritoEquipo(){

    for(var i = 0; i < resultadosEquipos.length; i++) {
      var resultadoTotalEquipos = resultadosEquipos[i];

      var capacidadEquipo = resultadosEquipos[i]["CAPACIDAD"];
      var idEquipo        = resultadosEquipos[i]["IDEQUIPO"];
      var imagenEquipo    = resultadosEquipos[i]["IMAGEN"];
      var marcaEquipo     = resultadosEquipos[i]["MARCA"];
      var modeloEquipo    = resultadosEquipos[i]["MODELO"];
      var precioEquipo    = resultadosEquipos[i]["PRECIO"];

      if (idEquipoGlobal == idEquipo) {
        
        var htmlEquiposAgregados =
        "<span class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetasTextoMediano'>Ingresa la cantidad para tu pedido</span>"+
        "<br>"+
        "<img class='colLg12 colLgPush10 colMd12 colMdPush10 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00 imagenProducto' src='../images/dispositivos/"+imagenEquipo+" 'alt='movil' style='width: 120px;'>"+
        "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetasTextoMediano infoProducto'>EQUIPO: "+marcaEquipo+" "+modeloEquipo+" "+capacidadEquipo+"</p>"+
        "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetasTextoMediano'>$ "+precioEquipo+"</p>"+
        "<input class='colLg08 colLgPush08 colMd08 colMdPush08 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00' type='number' name='cantidadEquiposIngreso' id='cantidadEquiposIngreso' placeholder='CANTIDAD'/>";

        var htmlBotones =
        "<div type='button' class='popupBtnCerrar closePopupAgregarPedido' data-dismiss='modal'><div class='cancelar'></div>Cancelar</div>"+
        "<div type='button' class='popupBtnConfirmar' onClick='agregarProducto("+idEquipo+", "+precioEquipo+");'><div class='continuar'></div>Continuar</div>";
        
        $(".contenidoAgregarPedido").html(htmlEquiposAgregados);
        $(".divBotonesPedidos").html(htmlBotones);
      }
    }
  }
  //====================================================================================================

  //FUCNION INGRESAR MSISDN=============================================================================
  function clickIngresarCarritoMsisdn(){
      var idChip = resultadosChips["idMsisdnTipo"];
      var tipoChip        = resultadosChips["msisdnTipo"];
      var descripcionChip    = resultadosChips["descripcion"];

    if (idMsisdnGlobal == idChip) {
      
      var htmlMsisdnAgregados =
      "<span class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetasTextoMediano'>Ingresa la cantidad para tu pedido</span>"+
      "<br>"+
      // "<img class='colLg12 colLgPush10 colMd12 colMdPush10 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00' src='../images/dispositivos/"+imagenEquipo+" 'alt='movil' style='width: 120px;'>"+
      "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetasTextoMediano'>TIPO DE CHIP: "+tipoChip+" "+descripcionChip+"</p>"+
      // "<p class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetasTextoMediano'>$ "+precioEquipo+"</p>"+
      // "<input type='hidden' class='precioEquipoSeleccionado' value='"+precioEquipo+"'/>"+
      "<input class='colLg08 colLgPush08 colMd08 colMdPush08 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00' type='number' name='cantidadEquiposIngreso' id='cantidadEquiposIngreso' placeholder='CANTIDAD'/>";

      var htmlBotones =
      "<div type='button' class='popupBtnCerrar closePopupAgregarPedido' data-dismiss='modal'><div class='cancelar'></div>Cancelar</div>"+
      "<div type='button' class='popupBtnConfirmar' onClick='agregarProducto("+idChip+");'><div class='continuar'></div>Continuar</div>";

      $(".contenidoAgregarPedido").html(htmlMsisdnAgregados);
      $(".divBotonesPedidos").html(htmlBotones);
    }
  }
  //====================================================================================================
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="popupAgregarCarrito" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modalDialog" role="document">
    <div class="modalContent paddingOff">
      <div class="modalHeader paddingOff">
        <button type="button" class="close cerrarPopupAgregarProducto" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">&times;</button>
        <div class="modalTitle centerText">AGREGAR CARRITO</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modalBody">
        <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form formCuerpoPadding0">
          <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOn contenedor cuerpoForm">
            <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetasForm contenidoAgregarPedido">
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modalFooter clear divBotonesPedidos">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form">
  <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm centerText">
    <button type='button' class='btnEncabezadoForm pullRight' onClick='regresarCarritoCompras();'><span class='btnCarritoCompras'>Carrito de compras</span></button>
    <label class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24">HACER PEDIDOS</label>
  </div>
  <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOn contenedor cuerpoForm Distri">
    <div class="colLg12 colMd12 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm">
      <button class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 contenidoEquipos" onclick="abrirContenidoEquipos();">Equipos</button>
    </div>
    <div class="colLg12 colMd12 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm">
      <button class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24" onclick="abrirContenidoMsisdn();">Msisdns</button>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="colLg10 colMd10 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm">
      <input type="text" class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 search hide" name="buscarArticulos" id="buscarArticulos" placeholder="BUSQUEDA. . ."/>
    </div>
    <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm carritoComprasVista">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24">
    <div class="colLg18 colMd18 colSm24 colXs24">
      <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form">
        <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm">ARTICULOS AGREGADOS
        </div>
        <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff cuerpoForm">
          <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff" id="contenidoTotalCarrito">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colLg06 colMd06 colSm24 colXs24 form">
      <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm">CATIDAD A PAGAR
        <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff cuerpoForm">
          <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff costoTotalPagar">
            <p class="etiquetasTextoMediano centerText totalEquiposText"></p>
            <input type="hidden" class="campoTotalEquipos">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24">
        <br>
        <button class="colLg12 colLgPush06 colMd12 colMdPush06 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00" onClick="enviarDatos(this);"><span class="btnPagar"></span>Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hola amigos disculpen tengo una duda hacerca de como puedo sacar los datos de una lista que tengo que es de un carrito de compras, lo que intento hacer es sacar los productos que tengo insertados es esa lista y meterlos a un arreglo para asi poder mandar el arreglo al backend ya que el archivo de backend asi me lo piden en un arreglo y lo que hace mi codigo es que sobrescribe la información me hace la posicion 0, 1, 2, etc... pero va sobrescribiendo en cada posiscion un el resultado anterior, les dejo mi funcion de front para ver si alguien ya a realizado esta problematica que estoy atorado y pudiera asesorarme para solucionarlo.

```js
function agregarProducto(idEquipo, precioEquipo){
  var catidadIngresada = $("#cantidadEquiposIngreso").val();

  var precioEquipoIngresado = precioEquipo;
  var infoProducto = $(".infoProducto").text();
  var imagenProducto = $(".imagenProducto").attr('src');
  

  var total = 0;
  var htmlMostrarDatosPedido = "";
  var htmlEquiposAgregados = "";
  var htmlPagoTotal = "";

  total = catidadIngresada;
  var totalCantidadPrecio = total * precioEquipo;


  htmlEquiposAgregados +=
      "<ul class='listaProductosAnadidos' id='listProdu'>"+
        "<li class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24' style='display: inline-block;'>"+
          "<label>"+
            "<img class='colLg10 colMd10 colSm24 colXs24' src='"+imagenProducto+"' alt='movil' style='width: 80px;'>"+
            "<p class='colLg10 colMd10 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetasTextoMediano infoProductos'>"+infoProducto+"</p>"+
            "<input class='colLg04 colMd04 colSm24 colXs24 totalCantidad' type='number' name='cantidadTotalEquipos' id='cantidadTotalEquipos' value='"+catidadIngresada+"'  placeholder='CANTIDAD'/>"+
            "<p class='colLg04 colMd04 colSm24 colXs24 etiquetasTextoMediano precioProducto'>$ "+precioEquipo+"</p>"+
            "<input type='hidden' class='precioEquipoSeleccionado' value='"+precioEquipo+"'/>"+
            "<button class='colLg02 colMd02 colSm24 colXs24 botonEliminar' value='"+idEquipo+"' onclick='eliminarElemento(this, "+totalCantidadPrecio+");'>X</button>"+
            "<input type='hidden' class='totalEquipos' value='"+totalCantidadPrecio+"'>"+
          "</label>"+
        "</li>"+
      "</ul>";
      $('#contenidoTotalCarrito').append(htmlEquiposAgregados);

       $("#listProdu li").each(function(){
            productos = {
             informacion: $('.infoProductos').text(),
             precio: $('.precioEquipoSeleccionado').val(),
             idProducto: $(".botonEliminar").val()
           }
       });
       prodArray.push(productos);
       console.log(productos);


    $(".closePopupAgregarPedido").click();
  var suma = 0;
  $('.totalEquipos').each(function(){

    if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
      suma += Number($(this).val());
      $(".totalEquiposText").text(moneda+suma.toFixed(2));
      $(".campoTotalEquipos").val(suma);
    }else{alert("NAN");}
  });
}
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML

Comment: listo añadi el html para que lo puedan ver, este lleva un popup tambien en donde al insertar un producto aparece un popup donde pueden insertar la cantidad y esta cantidad es la que se inserta al carrito

Comment: _Sacar datos de una lista y meterlos a un arreglo_? Una lista es un arreglo. Hay algún caso especial que requiera algo más que: `const nuevoArreglo = listaCarrito.map(equipo => equipo.IdEquipo);`

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias, lo que ise fue mejor hacerlo en una tabla les dejo mi codigo para que verifiquen quien tenga este problema, igual les explico...
dentro de la tabla que se construye cuando agregas un equipo los td tienen una clase resultado y ahi meti unos input ocultos en conde como valor tienen lo que muestras en la tabla como el precio la informacion la cantidad, que es lo que vas a mandar en el arreglo, y en la funcion de obtenerValoresTabla seleccionas la tabla con el id y llamas a todos los td con la clase resultados buscar dentro de todos los td los input y sacas el valor de cada input y los almacenas en el arreglo con las posiciones segun las columnass que tengas.
Espero haber ayudado a alguien con mi mismo problema.

```js
//FUNCION AGREGAR PRODUCTO=============================================================================
function agregarProductoEquipo(idEquipo, precioEquipo){
  var catidadIngresada = $("#cantidadEquiposIngreso").val();
  var descuentoIngresado = $("#descuentoEquiposIngreso").val();

  var precioEquipoIngresado = precioEquipo;
  var infoProducto = $(".infoProducto").text();
  var imagenProducto = $(".imagenProducto").attr('src');
  

  var total = 0;
  var htmlEquiposAgregados = "";

  total = catidadIngresada;
  var totalCantidadPrecio = total * precioEquipo;


  htmlEquiposAgregados +=

    "<tr class='resultados trHover'>"+
      "<td class='resultado'><img src='"+imagenProducto+"' alt='movil' style='width: 80px;'></td>"+
      "<td class='resultado'>"+infoProducto+"<input type='hidden' class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 informacionProducto' value='"+infoProducto+"'/></td>"+
      "<td class='resultado'><input class='colLg12 colLgPush06 colMd12 colMdPush06 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00 totalCantidad' type='number' name='cantidadTotalEquipos' value='"+catidadIngresada+"'/></td>"+
      "<td class='resultado'>%"+descuentoIngresado+"<input type='hidden' class='colLg12 colLgPush06 colMd12 colMdPush06 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00 descuentoEquipoSeleccionado' value='"+descuentoIngresado+"'/></td>"+
      "<td class='resultado'>$"+precioEquipo+"<input type='hidden' class='colLg12 colLgPush06 colMd12 colMdPush06 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00 precioEquipoSeleccionado' value='"+precioEquipo+"'/></td>"+
      "<td class='resultado tdClick elementsCenter seleccionImg' onClick='eliminarElemento(this, "+idEquipo+", "+totalCantidadPrecio+");'>"+
        "<input type='hidden' class='totalEquipos' value='"+totalCantidadPrecio+"'>"+
        "<div class='imgEliminar'></div>"+
      "</td>"+
    "</tr>";

      $('.contenidoEquiposTotalCarrito').append(htmlEquiposAgregados);

  $(".closePopupAgregarPedido").click();

  obtenerValoresTabla();
}
//====================================================================================================

//FUNCION OBTENER DATOS TABLA PRODUCTO================================================================
function obtenerValoresTabla() {
  var trs=document.querySelectorAll("#equiposAnadidosCarrito .resultados");
    for (var tr of trs) {
      var inputs=tr.querySelectorAll("input");
    }
  prodArray.push([inputs[0].value, inputs[1].value, inputs[2].value, inputs[3].value]);
}
//====================================================================================================
```

```html
<div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form">
  <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm centerText" id="cuerpoCarrito1">
    <button type='button' class='btnEncabezadoForm pullRight' onClick='regresarCarritoCompras();'><span class='btnCarritoCompras'>Carrito de compras</span></button>
    <label class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24">HACER PEDIDOS</label>
  </div>
  <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOn contenedor cuerpoForm Distri" id="cuerpoCarrito2">
    <div class="colLg12 colMd12 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm">
      <button class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 contenidoEquipos" onclick="abrirContenidoEquipos();">Equipos</button>
    </div>
    <div class="colLg12 colMd12 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm">
      <button class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 contenidoMsisdn" onclick="abrirContenidoMsisdn();">Msisdns</button>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="colLg10 colMd10 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm">
      <input type="text" class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 search hide" name="buscarArticulos" id="buscarArticulos" placeholder="BUSQUEDA. . ."/>
    </div>
    <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff etiquetasForm carritoComprasVista">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24" id="carritoCompraAgregados">
    <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm">CARRITO DE COMPRAS<span class='regresar'onClick='regresarBusquedaArticulos();'></span></div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="colLg18 colMd18 colSm24 colXs24">
      <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form">
        <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm">EQUIPOS AGREGADOS</div>
        <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff cuerpoForm">
          <div class='colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 form tabla'>
            <table id='equiposAnadidosCarrito'>
              <tbody class='contenidoEquiposTotalCarrito'>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colLg06 colMd06 colSm24 colXs24 form">
      <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm">TOTAL DE EQUIPOS
        <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff cuerpoForm">
          <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff costoTotalPagar">
            <p class="etiquetasTextoMediano centerText totalEquiposText"></p>
            <input type="hidden" class="campoTotalEquipos">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colLg06 colMd06 colSm24 colXs24 form">
      <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 encabezadoForm">CATIDAD A PAGAR
        <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff cuerpoForm">
          <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24 paddingOff costoTotalPagar">
            <p class="etiquetasTextoMediano centerText totalEquiposText"></p>
            <input type="hidden" class="campoTotalEquipos">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="colLg24 colMd24 colSm24 colXs24">
        <br>
        <button class="colLg12 colLgPush06 colMd12 colMdPush06 colSm24 colSmPush00 colXs24 colXsPush00" onClick="enviarDatos(this);"><span class="btnPagar"></span>Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```